# Documentation needed for a Canadian citizen living outside Canada to sponsor their spouse to immigrate to Canada

Tags: visa, canada, family, paperwork

According to the government of Canada [1],

> If you’re a Canadian citizen living outside Canada, you must show that you plan to live in Canada when the persons you want to sponsor become permanent residents.

However, on the form [IMM 1344](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm1344e.pdf), the sponsor is only asked which province they intend to live in with the sponsored person(s).

On form [IMM 5532](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5532e.pdf), the sponsor is asked when they left Canada, when they intend to return to Canada, and where they intend to live when they return to Canada.

Neither form explains how the sponsor is expected to "show" that they plan to live in Canada. What kind of evidence does IRCC expect?

[1] https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/family-sponsorship/spouse-partner-children/eligibility.html

Comment: Have you obtained the full application package? What does the document checklist specify (IMM 5533, I think)?

Comment: @Traveller IMM 5533 also says that one needs to provide proof, but doesn't say in what form.

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with this, but I would guess that they are not particularly strict about it.  Whatever you have showing a plan to live somewhere is probably fine, even if it's just a letter from a friend saying they're planning to let you sleep on the sofa while you search for an apartment.